# Getting latest status following the current record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the earliest update_date corresponding to AVLB status associated with an equipment, was wondering how to go about doing this.

Here is some of my test entries.

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| EQUNR  | UPDATE_DATE | UPDATE_TIME | SYS_STATUS |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 111111 | 16/12/2004  |      113943 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 1/07/2015   |      135327 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 30/05/2017  |       11628 | INST       |
| 111111 | 17/07/2017  |      154016 | INST       |
| 111111 | 17/07/2017  |      153348 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 2/08/2020   |       92803 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 3/08/2020   |      144704 | ESTO       |
| 111111 | 7/08/2020   |       95733 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 13/04/2021  |      111815 | ESTO       |
| 111111 | 10/05/2021  |      111914 | AVLB       |
| 111111 | 27/08/2021  |      225400 | INST       |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I need the earliest UPDATE_DATE corresponding to the AVLB status after the current row.

Expected output

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
| EQUNR  | UPDATE_DATE | UPDATE_TIME | SYS_STATUS | NEXT_AVLB_UPDATE_DATE |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 111111 | 16/12/2004  |      113943 | AVLB       | 1/07/2015             |
| 111111 | 1/07/2015   |      135327 | AVLB       | 17/07/2017            |
| 111111 | 30/05/2017  |       11628 | INST       | 17/07/2017            |
| 111111 | 17/07/2017  |      154016 | INST       | 17/07/2017            |
| 111111 | 17/07/2017  |      153348 | AVLB       | 2/08/2020             |
| 111111 | 2/08/2020   |       92803 | AVLB       | 7/08/2020             |
| 111111 | 3/08/2020   |      144704 | ESTO       | 7/08/2020             |
| 111111 | 7/08/2020   |       95733 | AVLB       | 10/05/2021            |
| 111111 | 13/04/2021  |      111815 | ESTO       | 10/05/2021            |
| 111111 | 10/05/2021  |      111914 | AVLB       | NULL                  |
| 111111 | 27/08/2021  |      225400 | INST       | NULL                  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

I tinkered around with using FIRST_VALUE and ROWS 1 FOLLOWING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING, however I wasn't able to get the desired output.

```
SELECT * 
    , FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN SYS_STATUS='AVLB' THEN UPDATE_DATE END) OVER(PARTITION BY EQUNR ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS NEXT_AVLB_STATUS
FROM #temptable
ORDER BY update_date
```

Any help on this would be great

Here is the sample script

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [EQUNR] nvarchar(18), [UPDATE_DATE] date, [UPDATE_TIME] nvarchar(6), [SYS_STATUS] nvarchar(4) )

INSERT INTO #temptable ([EQUNR], [UPDATE_DATE], [UPDATE_TIME], [SYS_STATUS])
VALUES
( N'111111 ', N'2004-12-16', N'113943', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2015-07-01', N'135327', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2017-05-30', N'011628', N'INST' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2017-07-17', N'154016', N'INST' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2017-07-17', N'153348', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2020-08-02', N'092803', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2020-08-03', N'144704', N'ESTO' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2020-08-07', N'095733', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2021-04-13', N'111815', N'ESTO' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2021-05-10', N'111914', N'AVLB' ),
( N'111111 ', N'2021-08-27', N'225400', N'INST' )

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: i am looking for the earliest date corresponding to "AVLB" status. For the first row(ie with the UPDATE_DATE=2004-12-16) the "next" earliest AVLB date is 2015-07-01, so i would like that to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a windowed `min` with a `case` expression seems to do the trick.

```
select *
    , min(case when SYS_STATUS = 'AVLB' then UPDATE_DATE else null end)
    over (partition by EQUNR order by UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_TIME rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as NEXT_AVLB_STATUS
from #temptable
order by EQUNR, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_TIME;
```

Comment: This looks good except for the entry corresponding to "2017-07-17"

Comment: The order needs to be UPDATE_DATE and then UPDATE_TIME. But even after concatenating i wasnt able to get the expected results though

Comment: SELECT *
   ,min(CASE WHEN SYS_STATUS='AVLB' THEN UPDATE_DATE END) OVER(PARTITION BY EQUNR ORDER BY CAST(CONCAT(UPDATE_DATE,' ',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,1,2),':',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,3,2),':',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,5,2)) AS DATETIME)
   ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS next_status
   --,CAST(CONCAT(UPDATE_DATE,' ',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,1,2),':',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,3,2),':',SUBSTRING(UPDATE_TIME,5,2)) AS DATETIME)
  FROM #temptable
ORDER BY update_date

Comment: absolutely right, i wasnt ordering my final result set using UPDATE_TIME and hence my confusion in the final results